# Remove attribute across all edittexts

Tags: android, android-edittext, autocorrect

Is it possible to remove a feature (autocorrect, in this case) across the entire app from every single edit text by running an extension? Our app has a lot of edit texts across several activities and I would like to avoid running over each file to hit every one just to avoid adding a line of code, if possible. I have a style set up for that each one is connected to and tried adding

```
<item name="android:inputType">textNoSuggestions</item>
```

But that didn't do anything. Some of these fields do have input type set to be just number, and others I set for things like `textCapWords` or `textPersonsName' and things like that. I believe I made sure to give each one some kind of input, so is it because of that that the style line wasn't working?

I'm aware that I can just make a custom edit text and apply that to each layout file, but that would defeat the purpose of not running through each file.

tl;dr - Is there a way to remove autocorrect across every single activity without editing each layout file?

Comment: "so is it because of that that the style line wasn't working?" -- yes, because your in-layout `inputType` is overriding the one from the style. "Is it possible to remove a feature... across the entire app from every single edit text by running an extension?" -- I don't know what "running an extension" means. You are welcome to write some code to do a traversal of your view hierarchy (after `setContentView()` or wherever you are setting up that hierarchy), find `EditText` widgets, and adjust them to suit. That's one helper method, plus a call to it from every activity/fragment.

Comment: Personally, I'd write a Ruby script and modify the existing layout files to `|` in the `textNoSuggestions` value, if you have over, say, 100 layout files.